# Relationships and Inheritance on Mapped Case Classes with Lift

Tags: scala, lift

I have a database with different kind of posts, so I made this:

```
sealed trait PostBase[T <: PostBase[T]] extends LongKeyedMapper[T] with IdPK {
  object owner extends LongKeyedForeignKey(this, User)

  object posted extends MappedDateTime(this)
}

case class TextPost() extends PostBase[TextPost] {
  // Hic sunt Dracones
}

case class PhotoPost() extends PostBase[PhotoPost] {
  // Hic sunt Ponies
}
```

I want to use case classes so I can do a `match` on the values I get from `User.posts`, see here:

```
class User extends MegaProtoUser[User] with OneToMany[Long, User] {
  def getSingleton = User

  object posts extends MappedOneToMany(/* ??? */)
}
```

So what do I have to put as the parameters of `MappedOneToMany` in order to get the posts of type `PostBase`? This kind of can only work when there's single table inheritance, am I right?